# Can I salvage reviews after changing product type?

Tags: products, product-type

We want to make some of our products as grouped products now but what happens to the reviews? If I make it a new product type with additional products I KNOW it's going to be like a new product in the eyes of a customer but the boss is nervous that I'm about to re-do products over and go from hundreds of reviews to none.

Is there a way to transfer them?